# unset the array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays. I'd like to merge them into one, but remove the redundant values. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `array_unique` function .

Example

```
<?php
$input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red");
$result = array_unique($input);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => green
    [0] => red
    [1] => blue
)
```

Comment: but this is only for single dimensional array...

if multi dimensional array what we do..